# found run time error its common problem but as a beginner can't solve that?

Tags: kotlin

as a beginner this easy error seems too tuff to solve, stuck with this one->
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
please guide me how to increase my heap space in intelli j IDEA.
thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it works for you:
Go to `settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler` and **increase** value of **`Build process heap size (Mbytes)`**

Comment: hey thanx mohamad liaghat it actually works.